# Is there any benefit to tilting the camera holder in a camera bag?

Tags: lens, equipment-protection, camera-bag, transport

Would it be a good practice to tilt the pad inside the camera bag that sticks to the its side in order to prevent the lens from touching the bottom **`Instead of | | making it \/`**? I recently bought a Vanguard Oslo bag just because it allows me to carry a few lenses as well as speed light and I've been thinking, would this be a good practice at all, I mean does leaving the camera upside down on its lens for a long time damage the contacts in the lens mount of the camera, and would this practice TECHNICALLY be of any benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean does leaving the camera upside down on its lens for a long time could damage the contacts in the lens mount of the camera, and would this practice TECHNICALLY be of any benefit?

There's no indication from camera manufacturers that there's any problem with storing a camera lens-down in a bag. That's how my bag works, and I've seen many others who store the camera the same way. The lens mount on a DSLR is plenty strong enough to support the weight of the camera, and if the lens is properly mounted there should be no undue strain on the electrical contacts.

The main benefit I can see to your V-shaped compartment is that it could provide some extra impact protection if you dropped your bag. The tradeoff, of course, is that it's a less efficient use of space. Arranging the dividers so that the camera fits somewhat snugly in its compartment should provide enough protection for most circumstances.

Comment: Well you are also a software developer who apparently seems to enjoy photography :D. Me too :P

Comment: Works out better than being a photographer who enjoys software development, at least for me.